# AWS Lambda SQS Trigger Assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been given a task to consume messages from an SQS queue from an external company which returns me a bucket and key from which I am to copy a file. This external company has set up a role that I can assume that gives me access to the SQS queue and the S3 bucket, but I have a problem. How do I assume that external role for my Lambda trigger? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'll assume the role in your Lambda and then interact with the external AWS account using temporary credentials.

Example with python.

```
import boto3

sts = boto3.client('sts')

role = sts.assume_role(
   RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ACCOUND_ID:role/EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ROLE",
   ExternalId="EXTERNAL_ID_CONFIGURED",
   RoleSessionName="RoleSessionNameYouWant")

credentials = role['Credentials']

# Interact with resoures from the external company account
external_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])

s3 = external_session.client('s3'),
sqs = external_session.client('sqs')
```

An external ID is optional but important when roles are given to third-parties to avoid [the confused deputy problem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html#external-id-purpose). Ask the third-party to configure an external id for your role if that wasn't done.

Comment: Sure, that's no problem, easy as pie. My question is specifically about using SQS to trigger the lambda, but the SQS queue I want to use as a trigger is on the other account. How can I make the Trigger use the assumed role?

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the clarification. It's not possible to add a lambda trigger using the external role, but you actually don't even need a role, SQS supports cross-account access, Here is a post that explains how it works: https://medium.com/@omphemetsemafoko/trigger-aws-lambda-function-using-a-cross-account-amazon-standard-sqs-queue-3142a94ed26c